# ASP .Net MVC Login con cuenta microsoft me redirige a la página de login o da error

Tags: login, asp, oauth, microsoft, owin

Tengo un problema de autenticación con cuentas miscoroft multitenant en mi aplicación Web desarrollada con ASP .Net.

La arquitectura de mi app web es de 3 capas: Capa de presentación (PTL), lógica de negocio (BLL) y acceso a datos (DAL).

El problema es que subo mis aplicación a un app service en Azure e inicialmente si alguien hace login con su cuenta empresarial le permite el ingreso normalmente. Pero llega un punto en el que ya no permite autenticarse a nadie. El login de microsoft se realiza pero al usuario le redirige a la página de login (y si vuelve a querer hacer login nuevamente le redirige a la pantalla de login, es decir se genera un bucle que no permitirá continuar).

En mi controlador se verifica si el usuario ha iniciado sesión y lo redirige a otra pantalla asi que ese no es el inconveniente.

Tambien hay el problema que me suele mostrar el siguiente mensaje idx21323 requirenonce is ' pii is hidden '. openid connect protocol validationcontext.nonce was null.

La versión de los paquetes de Owin es la 4.1.0

Adjunto el código de mi clase startup

Saludos

```
public partial class Startup
{
    const string MSATenantId = "9188040d-6c67-4c5b-b112-36a304b66dad";
    public static string clientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ClientId"];
    public static string clientSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ClientSecret"];
    private static string authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/v2.0";
    public static string redirectUri = "mi url de app service";
    private void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());

        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
        {
            ClientId = clientId,
            Authority = authority,
            RedirectUri = redirectUri,
            PostLogoutRedirectUri = redirectUri,
            Scope = "openid profile",
            ResponseType = "id_token",
            TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters { ValidateIssuer = false, NameClaimType = "name" },
            Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
            {
                AuthenticationFailed = this.OnAuthenticationFailedAsync,
                SecurityTokenValidated = this.OnSecurityTokenValidatedAsync
            }
        });
    }

    private Task OnSecurityTokenValidatedAsync(SecurityTokenValidatedNotification<OpenIdConnectMessage, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions> notification)
    {
        // Make sure that the user didn't sign in with a personal Microsoft account
        if (notification.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/tenantid").Value == MSATenantId)
        {
            notification.HandleResponse();
            notification.Response.Redirect("/");
        }

        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }

    private Task OnAuthenticationFailedAsync(AuthenticationFailedNotification<OpenIdConnectMessage, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions> notification)
    {
        notification.HandleResponse();
        notification.Response.Redirect("/?error=ShowError??signIn=true&errorMessage=" + notification.Exception.Message);
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: y como esta declarado el login

Comment: te refieres al controlador?